# overlapping a screen in android

Tags: android, scrollview

In the below layout i have a text view named as scanning device.In that am displaying a device name But my device list was displaying above the screen .

can any one please help me how to scroll view should be inside the device list.while scrolling the screen it was displaying the list of the devices but it is displaying above the screen.

want to display inside a screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/back"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/lamp_list"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/refresh"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/scanningProgress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/baground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scan_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_discovery"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/deviceListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the below layout connect textview was coming out of the layout.

device_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lamp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deviceName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="Solar Enviro SSL 2016" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_red_view"
        android:text="@string/connect"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop=".2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure your project can be compiled ? I getting inflate xml issue

Comment: yes compiled...

Comment: @JohnJoe can you please help me where i did the misatake

Comment: Just wonder why your code can be compiled but I can't. Can you post how you populate the item to listview?

Comment: @JohnJoe already posted the device list

Comment: first off, linear layout is not allowed inside the widget toolbar and can you post a screenshot of the problem...?

Comment: Yes, @X-Black is right. You should post screenshots and give a more clear idea of what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @AmanB. please check shared screenshot

Comment: @jyothichandra where is the screenshot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740090/layout-overlapping-in-android-xml?noredirect=1#comment98157528_55740090

Answer (score 0):

change this things..
used both wrap_content. i hope you also remove default action bar.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scan_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/deviceListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: connect button should display inside.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CoordinatorLayout use linear layout.

if u r a beginner start coding with linear layout. It is easy to understand.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```