# layout overlapping in android xml

Tags: android, overlapping

[check the screen shot connect button is overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plq1i.jpg)
Hi in the below code displaying recylerview to displaying list of items.In that am using two layouts.one is device item and scan device.

In device_item layout am displaying list of items and scan device displaying with background.
because of the device item layout was displaying above the background images.

want to display inside the background image want to display list of items.

scan_devices.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/back"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/lamp_list"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/refresh"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/scanningProgress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/baground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scan_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_discovery"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/deviceListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

device_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lamp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deviceName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="Solar Enviro SSL 2016" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_red_view"
        android:text="@string/connect"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop=".2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Need more clarity. I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AmanB. please check the screenshots

Comment: please post xml for footer too

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55721811/edit) to update the information there.

Comment: @pawar no footer dispalyed background image contains footer too